# How can I retrieve data from a SD Card when photorec doesn't work?

Tags: sd-card, file-recovery, io

A friend of mine took pictures of a Halloween party with his camera, and when he put the SD card in his computer, some of the pictures went missing. Knowing that I have successfully rescued his HD with testdisk, he asked me if I could do something about it. I told him no to use the SD card anymore until I can do something with it, in order to prevent remaining data to be erased.

I first opened the SD Card folder in Nautilus, and I got this error:

[image: error when reading with Nautilus]
*Quick translation: Impossible to show content of this folder, I/O error on **weird filename***

This weird file was nowhere to be seen in Nautilus. Moreover, when right clicking on the "112_FUJI" folder, selecting "properties", it tells me that the folder holds for more than 21GB of data, and the SD Card has a capacity of 8GB...

I ran photorec on the SD card, got many things back (wanted as well as unwanted stuff: mp3, doc, zip, aif files), but none of the picture he took that night. *(Just to clarify, we're 100% sure he took the picture, that they were recorded to the SD, that we didn't deleted them, AND that I'm working on the good SD card)*

So, I told him that my recovering skills ends at the same point that testdisk and foremost does, and told him I could do nothing more for him. But then, I opened the SD card folder with a terminal emulator, and I found something else:

[image: trying to read file with a terminal emulator]
(please note that this is only the end of the `ll` command in the folder, there are a few more weird files/folder at the beginning, but the end was more relevant for a screenshot)

So there seems to be a bunch of files and folder that are here, but that I can't access for some reasons (Bad sectors? Anything else? I don't know, my skills aren't that extended). Anyway, they might be the picture we're looking for (pun intended), but as you can see, this is a huge mess. Non-ASCII characters, unknown rights on the files, ... (and we might have an explanation of why it says it holds more than 8GB)

So here are my questions:

1. How can I retrieve data of those files/folder (assuming they are the pictures I'm looking for)
2. How did this mess happened? How to prevent it (but this is just me being curious, the priority is to get back the data)

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: It looks it is this issue (see USBC entries in directory): https://superuser.com/a/1657764/705502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may well be close to the end of the line for "regular" data recovery.  What I would do is use (GNU) DDRescue to make a bitcopy of the SD card - or as much of it as you can get, and then try use Testdisk to [Repair the FAT Tables](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Advanced_FAT_Repair) (ie by looking at the backup copy of the File Allocation Table)

You might also - on a bit copy of the drive, attempt to run [checkdisk /f](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd637756.aspx) to try and force it to fix the drive - this might help - it might also make the problem a lot worse.

Its anyones guess how the problem happened - the card going faulty is, I suspect the most likely cause, it could also have been a problem with the firmware/software in the Camera, and/or maybe it came loose during the middle of a write.

Comment: I managed to get a few files back by using `chkdsk /f`, some others seems to be lost for ever.
It did nothing on the files with strange names thought. Thank you

Comment: `chkdsk /f` is the worst thing one can do with a broken disk! Such a disk should not be modified at all until all possible recovery procedures are exhausted, or one risks losing data.

Comment: @harrymc - hence the words immediately prior "You might, also - on a bit copy of the drive..." and "it might also make the problem a lot worse"

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like the poster picked up that bit of advice instead of using every other possible tool before giving up.

Comment: Don't worry, I still have a dd copy of the SD card. Repairing the FAT table gave me some strange results and didn't allowed me to get any files back that's why I didn't mentioned it

Comment: @Tloz: The utilities I mentioned don't need the FAT repaired, but you will need to reset the card to its broken state.

Answer (score -1):

SD cards are prone to hardware problems. Once such a problem has occurred,
the card needs to be replaced.

For recovering the data, the best recovery programs are :

1. [MiniTool Power Data Recovery](http://www.powerdatarecovery.com/) (Free Edition)
   I count it as the best of its kind.
   Available on Windows and Mac.
   The free version has a limit of 1GB of recovered data.
2. [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)
3. [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
4. [PC Inspector File Recovery](http://www.pcinspector.de/Default.htm?language=1)
5. [Puran File Recovery](http://www.puransoftware.com/File-Recovery.html)

Comment: Why downvote a correct answer?

Comment: A correct answer for a different question. It's easy to got this list by googling any words related to data recovery and looking for some alternatives to alternative.to, but I was looking for something more in depth than just a list of software (that some has already been tried)

Comment: Excuse me for trying to help, but the question was how to save the data, not so? I have tried all of these products in the past, and each has its good points. The "easy googling" part will get you many dozens of such products with big claims. Downvoting people who try to help will not get you far.