# diskgenuis shows two partitions sized 450MB on a 500GB disk that is unreadable

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a 500GB external disk that suddenly stopped working with error "the disk structure is corrupted and unreadable". chkdsk can't continue. IN disk genuis, i see the following:

[image]

I am trying to recover some documents. what should steps should I take?

In windows diskmanagement, the H: drive shows RAW filesystem.

Comment: Try Recuva (cc cleaner) and see. External Disks are usually not the best quality and so it is likely broken.

Comment: You may try the recovery products listed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1051463/8672).